# Save the iTunes download queue

Tags: itunes

Is there a way to save the download queue in iTunes ? I had to reboot my Macbook, and to my surpise, the queue was empty when I restarted iTunes. Is this behaviour intended ?

Edit:

It appears that this problem was related to the fact that my installation was not a clean install but an upgrade. It was OS X 10.7 upgraded to OS X 10.8. I did a fresh install, and now everything is back to normal; the queue is correctly saved and restored across sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this problem was related to the fact that my installation was not a clean install but an upgrade. It was OS X 10.7 upgraded to OS X 10.8.

I did a fresh install, and now everything is back to normal; the queue is correctly saved and restored across sessions.

Answer (score 0):

It should still be there, if it never downloaded? I suggest you contact in to Apple iTunes Support and explain you had items in your downloads queue, when you restarted, they disappeared.

First try signing out and back into your iTunes Store account in iTunes, if they download queue is still empty, email in.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apple's KBase #HT1725](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1725):

Your download might not complete for one of the following reasons:

> Quitting iTunes before a download is complete. Restarting the computer
>   during a download. Disconnecting from the Internet while downloading.
>   Slow or dropped Internet connection. Other applications blocking the
>   download, such as security software not manufactured by Apple or a
>   firewall. If your download was interrupted on your computer You will
>   be prompted to resume your download the next time you quit and reopen
>   iTunes. You can also manually restart the download with the following
>   steps.
>
> Resuming downloads from a computer
>
> Open iTunes. Choose Store > Check for Available Downloads. Enter your
>   account name and password. Click the "Check Downloads" button. Click
>   the Resume or Resume All button, or the resume arrow  to resume the
>   download.